# How do i measure count of outgoing requests to redis from my worker processes?

Tags: networking, redis, monitoring

I have a set of processes read from and write to Redis frequently. Sometimes I change a logic reduces requests count and I want to output it.
I can add a special counter in a code but I guess it isn't good practice...

Is there a utility/proxy/sniffer and etc helps me or can I do this in a Redis server side?

Answer (score 0):

you should do the following.

```
redis-cli info commandstats
```

The above will give you the various commands that have executed on redis.
You can also reset them by writing.

```
redis-cli resetstat
```

If you write a script which continuously hits this every interval and parse the data, you can plot a graph of various commands over time.

Comment: It is simple and obvious, but I would like to decide this on OS layer with some utility such as wireshark. Wireshark is not simple unfortunately)